# Datatable aliases not present in result

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me why results out of datatable, not containscolumns aliases? I do a few inner joins and put some aliases in the query, nevertheless when seeing datatable result seems like the result put the number at the end of the column instead of my aliases names. Is it something that can be fixed or? For instance when I have

```
SELECT us.Name, it.Name FROM table1 As us INNER JOIN table2 As it.name ON us.Id = it.Id;
```

in the result I get:

```
Name, Name1
```

instead of what I expected:

```
us.Name, it.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

The `us` and `it` you are referring to are **table** aliases, not **column** aliases.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT us.Name as 'us.Name', it.Name as 'it.Name'
FROM table1 As us 
INNER JOIN table2 As it.name ON us.Id = it.Id;
```

Or whatevever column alias you want of course.

Answer (score 1):

Both `us.Name` and `it.Name` refer to a column called `Name`, which is what you get in your result set.

To get what you want, you can change your query as follows:
`SELECT us.Name AS 'us.Name', it.Name AS 'it.Name' FROM table1 As us INNER JOIN table2 As it.name ON us.Id = it.Id;`, this should yield what you are after.